# How to reduce the background colour length of a node in Jtree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treecellrenderer

Basically am setting a background color for the selected component/node in the Jtree.
But the problem is the background color length is exceeding the length of the node text.
So can anybody tell on how to control the length of the background color? I want the background color of any node to be adjusted according to the text length of a node.

Comment: Swing in 2016? Why not JavaFX?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724913/color-row-in-jtree) may help you